# Create Heroku App.json after manual deploy and configuration of App

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I have successfully deployed my app on Heroku, added add-ons, updated env var via the control-panel settings, etc. I am now looking at creating an app.json after the fact. Is it possible to query Heroku in some way to have an app.json generated from the hosted application that I've created?

Comment: Can't believe nobody knows the answer to this. Heroku documentation is very confusing, all I want was to generate the `app.json` too.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found the answer via another SO post: Heroku provides an App.json-creation tool. Simply log into Heroku, navigate to your app and add "/app-json" to the end.

For example:

`https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/your-app-name/app-json`

Comment: Whaaaaaaat? Woah!

Comment: Hero. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sure there is a CLI command for this but I cannot find it now!

Comment: Any reason why this is so well hidden ? Are they deprecating it ? Is there any other way to access this page ?